# How to extract a list of embedded resources from C# assembly?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I just want to extract some **embedded resources** or a list of them from my assembly to a directory. I used `File.Stream`, `WriteAllBytes` and also `File.Copy`, but it did NOT work, and its only an output with 0 bytes of size. Whats the problem with this?

```
public void Main()
{
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
    Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("myNameSpace.myEmbeddedRes");
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("e:\\new.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
    for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
    fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

or

```
private static void ExtEmbdRes(string outDir, string resLoc, List<string> files)
{
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        using (System.IO.Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resLoc + "." + file))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(outDir, file), System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
                {
                    fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
                }
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}


static void Main()
{
    List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
    {
        fileList.Add("txtFile1.txt");
        fileList.Add("txtFile2.txt");
        fileList.Add("txtFile3.txt");
    };
    ExtEmbdRes("e:\\", "myNameSpace", fileList);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your resource file is defined as Embedded Resource?

Comment: Thanx for your instant, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() to Get a list of embedded Resources. Also are you sure the executing assembly is the one with the embedded resources? Perhaps you are using a class library

Comment: By twiddling with VS n code i finally found that apparently the manifest UAC elevating is affecting and When I do that without setting `requestedExecutionLevel` on `requireAdministrator` or so, it works properly! What to do now?